# Threadlock Permatex 24200 vs 24209

Tags: threadlocker

I am preparing myself to safety my car. And one of the important components when dealing with wheels and brakes is thread-locks. I decided to go the Permatex brand, thought anyone should just work fine.

I am wondering on what would be the difference between these two products:

- [Permatex 24200 Medium Strength Threadlocker Blue, 6 ml](https://www.amazon.ca/Permatex-24200-Medium-Strength-Threadlocker/dp/B0002UEMZ2/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=lock+tight+vibratite&qid=1623626141&sr=8-15)
- [Permatex 24209 Blue Medium Strength 242 Threadlocker, 6ml](https://www.amazon.ca/Permatex-27-070-MEDIUM-STRENGTH-THREADLOCKER/dp/B07DY6MD6V/ref=sr_1_16?dchild=1&keywords=lock+tight+vibratite&qid=1623626141&sr=8-16)

From the image the `Permatex 24209` also says `24200` on the corner. So, for me it is really confusing about the differences.

---

I already did some research on this topic. Here are some useful links I found.

- [The Ultimate Threadlocker Competition--Which is the Best?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-uN-d7XtL4)
  from which I got the following comparison results.

[image]

- [Parmatex - Threadlock](https://www.permatex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/PX-0716-2019-Threadlocker-Selector-Chart.pdf)
- [Loctite - Threadlocking Technical Guide](http://wdarc.org/Loctite%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not quite sure why you'd use threadlocker on either of these parts? If you torque the lugs on the wheels correctly, there should be no issue. As for brakes, even with threadlocker on there, the brakes get hot enough it will melt the threadlocker and cause it to not work anymore. Really, IMHO, you're just wasting your money and time using threadlocker on these.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable feedback. It would be mainly for the callipers as per used by [ChrisFix](https://youtu.be/6RQ9UabOIPg?t=522). Not for the wheel nuts as implied by my question.

Comment: Again, even the red threadlocker wouldn't hold due to the heat from the brakes.  And the red is as strong as it gets. It's a waste of time and money. Even the venerable Chrisfix gets it wrong sometimes. There's no reason to put it on the caliper bolts.

Comment: You should only use threadlocker where the service manual calls for it.  I have never seen any brake or wheel components that called for any type of threadlocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the number is either a mistake on the amazon.ca website or it's an alternate part number for the same product. This is listed as 24200 on the [Permatex website](https://www.permatex.com/products/thread-compounds/threadlockers/permatex-medium-strength-threadlocker-blue-2/?locale=en_us) and they don't list a 24209 part number. The Canadian part number is 24206.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The two products have the same `6 ml` but they have different weights `27.2g` vs `18.1g` so I thought they would be different. Could that difference in weight be due to the material of the tube container given that the wrapping is mostly the same?